# How can I know which version of Visual Studio a Visual Studio solution is created by?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-2022

I need to build a C# solution but do not know which version of Visual Studio it was created by. I installed Visual Studio 2017 but got build errors like:

> CS1617    Invalid option 'preview' for /langversion. Use '/langversion:?'
> to list supported values.

I opened the .sln file with an editor and saw the following lines:

```
   Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00   
   #Visual Studio 15   
   VisualStudioVersion = 15.0.28010.2050  
   MinimumVisualStudioVersion = 10.0.40219.1
```

I'm confused about the numbers. Why is the format version different from the VisualStudioVersion. Does Visual Studio 15 mean Visual Studio 2015? If not, is there a list showing the correspondence between the VisualStudioVersion and real Visual Studio commercial names?

Comment: [2017](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2017/install/visual-studio-build-numbers-and-release-dates?view=vs-2017&preserve-view=true) -> 15, [2019](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/visual-studio-build-numbers-and-release-dates?view=vs-2019&preserve-view=true) -> 16, [2022](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/visual-studio-build-numbers-and-release-dates?view=vs-2022) -> 17

Comment: VS 15 version is VS 2017, but usually you don't need the same version, the latest should be fine. There is something else going wrong.

Comment: I don't know but I would assume that the solution file format hasn't changed with every new VS version so I would think that the format version 12 means that the file format hadn't changed since VS 2012 when that soluti8on was created.

Comment: The [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/visual-studio/info) for Visual Studio shows the correspondence between names (i.e. with years in them) and the actual version numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written in this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/productinfo/release-rhythm#determining-your-product-edition-version-and-channel), 2022 starts with 17 start as a major release

Regarding the documents corresponding to the currently commonly used 2022, 2019, and 2017 versions, thanks to shingo for the proposal.

They are:

[2017](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2017/install/visual-studio-build-numbers-and-release-dates?view=vs-2017&preserve-view=true#visual-studio-2017)->15

[2019](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/visual-studio-build-numbers-and-release-dates?view=vs-2019&preserve-view=true#visual-studio-2019)->16

[2022](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/visual-studio-build-numbers-and-release-dates?view=vs-2022&preserve-view=true#visual-studio-2022)->17

Usually you can open programs compiled in previous versions in the latest version.